# select2 and .datetimepicker is not a function

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I'm encountering some issues with the Select2. I'm trying to initialize the library and it's shows in my console that Select2 is not a function. Then if I remove the Select2 reference the DatetimePicker library will show an error too, the same as Select2. I'm not sure if this is because of the libraries that I'm using.

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/select2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/moment.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/parsley.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/cropper.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

```js
$(".select2-selectfield").select2();

$('.datepicker').datetimepicker({
  format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
});

$('.tablesorter').DataTable({
  searching: false
});

$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
```

Comment: That sounds like the paths to the JS files are wrong.

Comment: Also note that you're including select2.min.js twice

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan still not working even I remove the other one.

Comment: Have you corrected the file paths?